# GNOME Shell's search function doesn't work properly

Tags: gnome

I've just installed GNOME Shell on Ubuntu 11.10. I toyed a little with some GNOME Shell extensions, and now suddenly, the search box in the main menu doesn't work properly.

When I search for an application or a file, the corresponding application or file doesn't show up.

I removed all the extensions but nothing changed. I even reinstalled GNOME Shell itself, but in vain.

What should I do?

Comment: I have the same or very similar problem. 1) When I press the Super key and type the name of an app, the app dows not show up in a lens, but if I press Enter, the app runs anyway. 2) If I search for the Back Up app (Deja Dup), it doesn't find it at all, but it is installed on my system and I can run it in other ways, e.g., from the command line.

Comment: Could you describe how it looks like or provide a screen-shot? It is not clear (to me) from your description whether there is at all any icon that shows up on the overview or not. Also what extensions did you install, were these all extensions supported by Gnome?

Comment: this was exactly the same with me .

Comment: and i'm sorry i replied a bit late .

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned and unanswered, could you perhaps add more detail to your question? If this question no longer applies then you can either delete it or answer it yourself if you've solved the problem. Thanks!